# My CSS's wont apply to my application rendered through zappa\express\node.js

Tags: css, node.js, coffeescript, express, zappa

A copy of my code is here
http://pastebin.com/jcLRCrQr

Everything loads fine and the CCS sheets resolve, the javascript\coffescript files load and work correctly, however the styles fail to apply

a wierd thing is when i access the css files directly i.e /lib/css/bootstrap.css 
they do not come out formatted, infact its as if all the whitespace has been stripped out.

I have tried this in firefox and chromium and get the same issue.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the inspector to see what rules are being parsed and what styles are applied to the elements?

Comment: Could you provide a pastebin of the compiled HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out , thanks to all that had a go.

the content type had to be set on the response for each .css file

i.e res.contentType "css"